# Play Framework/ Eclipse/ Action not found

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

Hi I am new to Play Framework and till now experience is really bad with it. Every tutorial that I watch or do I get some stupid errors which I cannot fix. I am a step away from leaving this play framework. Anyway this is my last error that I got:

If I go to localhost:9000/example i get this error

Action not found
For request 'GET /example'
These routes have been tried, in this order:

```
1GET/controllers.Application.index()
2GET/example/controllers.Application.example()
3GET/assets/$file<.+>controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)
```

My Application.java looks like that:

```
 package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Play Tutorial :)"));
    }

    public static Result example(){

        String s = "Hello Mr View";
        return ok(fun.render(s));
    }

}
```

This is my routes file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page

GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /example/                   controllers.Application.example()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And this is my fun.scala.html file:

```
@(message: String)

<h1>@message</h1>
```

I am doing this from this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mST2YmQYgS8&list=PL177265F762D05F72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove slash at the end of resource name in routes file like this

```
GET     /example                   controllers.Application.example()
```

Comment: Somehow I knew it, that was something very stupid at the end. Thank you very much!